# onKeyDown quando o Spinner está aberto

Tags: android, spinners

Olá estou tentando fazer uma ação quando um usuário fecha o spinner usando o botão voltar do dispositivo.

Mas o evento "onKeyDown" não é executado quando o spinner está aberto, somente se ele está fechado.

Como poderia estar detectando que o spinner foi fechado?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O evento de KEY não funciona porque ele vai ser disparado na activity do "Spinner" que está ativo. Segue abaixo um exemplo de como solucionar.

```
Spinner oi = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.meuspinner);
oi.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                //Faço a tratativa aqui.
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

E se você usar o **onBackPressed**?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   //aqui você controla o voltar fisico do aparelho
}
```

Comment: Não funciona. Já descobri o motivo e a correção vou estar postando aqui.